# mysql compare 2 substring columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find how many simular domains there are in a table according to the emails table.

Sample data:

```
domains              emails
_______              ______ 
gmail.nl             test@google.com
gmail.com            test@gmail.com
gmail.uk
```

I tried using this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domains
    WHERE 
    right(domain, INSTR(domain, '.')-1) 
    LIKE 
    CONCAT('%', right(email, length(email)-INSTR(email, '@')), '%')) as "total",
    right(email, length(Email)-INSTR(Email, '@')) FROM emails GROUP BY email
```

Here I'm comparing a part of a string from one table with another substring from another table.
Take a look at this DBFIDDLE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdf9iwaEPPz6kMpHqWhZkh/0

I'm getting 0 as result for each row, but it should be 3 for gmail.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Those are in the dbfiddle

Comment: that query is not a valid sql query. you have several errors to fix like two from clause

Comment: Whats wrong about it, could you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think Ill fixed it:

This my query now:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domains
    WHERE 
    emails.email
    LIKE 
    CONCAT('%', LEFT(domain, INSTR(domain, '.')-1), '%') 
    ) as "total",
    right(emails.email, length(emails.email)-INSTR(emails.email, '@')) FROM emails GROUP BY emails.email
```

I got the desired result!
I switched the columns and removed the substring from email.